# Upload a file using selenium(python) , the input element being inside a iframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Here is the outer html

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <div id="logo"></div>
            <div class="feedback_wrap">
                <span id="rating-ask" style="display: inline-block;">
                    <span class="ext_text">Rate us</span>
                    <br>
                    <span class="stars">
                        <a class="star" data-pos="1">
                            <span class="empty" style="display: inline;"></span>
                            <span class="filled" style="display: none;"></span>
                        </a>
                         <a class="star" data-pos="2">
                           <span class="empty" style="display: inline;"></span>
                            <span class="filled" style="display: none;"></span>
                        </a>
                         <a class="star" data-pos="3">
                            <span class="empty" style="display: inline;"></span>
                            <span class="filled" style="display: none;"></span>
                        </a>
                         <a class="star" data-pos="4">
                           <span class="empty" style="display: inline;"></span>
                            <span class="filled" style="display: none;"></span>
                        </a>
                         <a class="star" data-pos="5">
                            <span class="empty" style="display: inline;"></span>
                            <span class="filled" style="display: none;"></span>
                        </a>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="device_toggler_wrap">
                <div class="device_toggler_wrap2">
                    <span class="phone_icon"></span>
                    <div class="device_toggler">
                        <label class="switch">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="deviceswitch">
                            <span class="slider round"></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <span class="tablet_icon"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="device_color_switcher">
                <div class="device_color_switcher_row">
                    <div class="color color_1" data-color="#FDD8D5"></div>
                    <div class="color color_2" data-color="#F1D9BF"></div>
                    <div class="color color_3" data-color="#E6E7E9"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="device_color_switcher_row">
                    <div class="color color_4" data-color="#35383D"></div>
                    <div class="color color_5" data-color="#000000"></div>
                    <div class="color color_6" data-color="#873239"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="device_color_switcher_row">
                    <div class="color color_7" data-color="#54E9DD"></div>
                    <div class="color color_8" data-color="#28B3D4"></div>
                    <div class="color color_9" data-color="#A7A7A7"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="phone_wrap">
            <div class="phone" style="border-color: rgb(230, 231, 233); width: 340px; max-height: 650px; border-width: 28px 7px 50px;">
                <div class="arrow_left">
                    <span class="ext_icon"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="arrow_right">
                    <span class="ext_icon"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="label">
                    <span class="text" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="insta_loading" style="display: none;">
                    <i class="icon"></i>
                    <span class="text">Loading...</span>
                </div>
                <div id="iframe_wrap" style="width: 340px; opacity: 1;"><iframe frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
                <div class="circle"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the inner iframe:
https://gist.github.com/ishandutta2007/67c1698b34e58634b9a855051b67fdfd

This is my effort:

```
iframe = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe")
browser.switch_to.frame(iframe)

try:
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector("form > input").send_keys("/my/path/to/sample.jpg")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

No exception thrown but nothing happens either

Comment: Can you share html code ?

Comment: Why are you switching to default content AFTER you get the IFRAME? If you are inside of another IFRAME already (requiring the switch), you want to switch and then get the IFRAME. If you aren't, no need to switch to default content. Are you sure that there's only one `INPUT` inside the form? If so, is the first INPUT the one you want? You need to do some more debugging and then come back and edit the question and add the details that you found to the question.

Comment: ommited  switching to default content, but of no help. Yes I have looped and verified that it is one and only input inside iframe.

Comment: to add the reason I am not looping here is in that case I was getting error `Message: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: Error: element is not attached to the page document`, but doesn't matter much its the first input.